# Not root user does not have access on Mounted SSD

Tags: mount, permissions, ssd, users

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I am the administrator/root user "lex".

Recently I installed [Sync](https://www.resilio.com/), this program created user "rslsync". 
I have mounted SSD on startup and I want to sync couple of folder from this mounted disk, however the user "rslsync" does not have access to it and hence the program Sync too.

Here is my fstab (comments removed):

```
lex@lex-N501JW:~$ sudo cat /etc/fstab 
UUID=908d89c2-81bc-4b19-8d70-6300cd1e3334 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=A063-FDD7  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=f2b4f98d-8978-4c1a-9d38-202194e0a93c /media/lex/mystorage ext4 defaults 0 2
```

As you can see my SSD is mounted on startup on /media/lex/mystorage.

Some information about permissions:

```
lex@lex-N501JW:~$ sudo ls -la /media/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Апр 24  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root 4096 Окт 22 11:41 ..
drwxrwxr-x+  3 lex  lex  4096 Сен 25 11:36 lex

lex@lex-N501JW:~$ sudo ls -la /media/lex/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x+  3 lex  lex  4096 Сен 25 11:36 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Апр 24  2016 ..
drwxrwxr-x  23 lex  lex  4096 Окт 25 00:29 mystorage

lex@lex-N501JW:~$ sudo ls -la /media/lex/mystorage/
total 100200856
drwxrwxr-x   23 lex lex         4096 Окт 25 00:29 .
drwxrwxr-x+   3 lex lex         4096 Сен 25 11:36 ..
drwxrwxr-x    4 lex lex         4096 Окт 23 20:09 BitTorrentBox
```

Information about "lex" user:

```
lex@lex-N501JW:~$ id
uid=1000(lex) gid=1000(lex) groups=1000(lex),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),999(docker)
```

As you can see user and group "lex" has access to /media/lex/mystorage/ and I see this disk in nautilus and everything is OK.
I added "rslsync" user to group "lex" but this is not enough.

When I switch to user "rslsync" and try (the same error from Sync GUI):

```
lex@lex-N501JW:~$ su rslsync 
Password: 

rslsync@lex-N501JW:/home/lex$ ls -la /media/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Апр 24  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root 4096 Окт 22 11:41 ..
drwxrwxr-x+  3 lex  lex  4096 Сен 25 11:36 lex

rslsync@lex-N501JW:/home/lex$ ls -la /media/lex/
ls: cannot open directory '/media/lex/': Permission denied
```

Information about "rslsync" user:

```
rslsync@lex-N501JW:/home/lex$ id
uid=999(rslsync) gid=998(rslsync) groups=998(rslsync),46(plugdev),1000(lex)
```

After some time of researching I tried to add user "rslsync" to group "plugdev" but this does not work too as you can see.

I think there is some tricky part with this mounted SSD. Does anyone have an idea how "rslsync" can access /media/lex/mystorage/ ?

Comment: You are automounting the disk, with default options, from `/etc/fstab`. That should mean it mounts as `root:root`. However your `ls -l /media/lex` shows it is mounted as `lex:lex`. How come?

Comment: It was initially. But I as "lex" user could not write anything to mounted disk. Even in nautilus. So I changed chown lex:lex -R for /media/lex/*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you automount the disk, with default options, from `fstab`, the `plugdev` (or other) groups don't enter the picture.  This is a standard mount.  It is strange though, that it doesn't mount as `root:root`.

The permissions on `/media/lex` and `/media/lex/mystorage` are fine, and given that the other user is member of group `lex`, it should have `rwx` access to both directories.

I suspect what is blocking access is the ACL set on `/media/lex`.  Your `ls -l` output shows a `+` on `/media/lex`.  This indicates additional permissions have been set, possibly preventing non-owners from accessing the path.  Use `getfacl /media/lex` to see the permissions, and `setfacl` to change them.

If you simply want to get rid of the ACL, `setfacl -b /media/lex` should do the job.

Comment: Info:
`lex@lex-N501JW:~$ getfacl /media/lex
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/lex
# owner: lex
# group: lex
user::rwx
user:lex:r-x
group::---
mask::rwx
other::r-x`

Comment: I did `setfacl -b /media/lex` as a result I see that user is empty : `lex@lex-N501JW:~$ getfacl /media/lex`
`getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names`
`# file: media/lex`
`# owner: lex`
`# group: lex`
`user::rwx`
`group::---`
`other::r-x`  but I still don't have access as "rslsync".

Comment: `setfacl -m "g:lex:rwx" /media/lex` solved the problem!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @АлексейВолодько good to hear! Please mark the question solved by ticking this anwer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

You need to give "others" write permissions or you add user "rslsync" to the group "lex".

To give "others" write permissions you should do the following

```
sudo chmod o+rwx /media/lex/mystorage
```

than everything shozuld be good to go.

Comment: Since `ls /media/lex` already gives a permission  error, setting writeability further down can't be the solution.

Comment: yeah - thats right - perhaps the rights should be granted to the whole tree via "-R" sudo chmod -R o+rwx /media/lex/

Comment: No, that won't solve the problem, as `/media/lex` already has `rwx` permission and still gives both a read and write error.

Comment: but not to "others" thats what happen through my suggested command... right?

Comment: Your command indeed sets permission for others to `rwx`. However, (1) the others group doesn't need (and should rarely be given) write permissions on a directory; (2) instead the `rslsync` user was added to the `lex` group, by virtue of which it got `rwx` permissions on the directory; and (3) the "others" already had `r-x` and yet **reading** the directory (`ls -l /media/lex/`) failed with a permissions error. Giving others `w` permissions isn't going to change that.

Comment: point! you are right